# iteration through TableAdapter of a strongly typed DataSet

Tags: vb.net, iteration, strongly-typed-dataset, tableadapter

We would like to use a For-Next loop to iterate through a TableAdapter row by row and extract the value of a column in each row from a strongly typed DataSet.

The TableAdapter was created in the Visual Studio DataSet designer. The following names have been used for the database objects.

```
DataSet Name:      DataSetSchedules
DataTable Name:    DataTableSchedules
TableAdapter Name: DataTableDataAdapterSchedules
```

This is the coding I have started:

```
Dim strClassName As String = ""
Dim objAadapter As New DataSetSchedulesTableAdapters.DataTableTableAdapterSchedules
Dim objDataTable As DataSetSchedulesTableAdapters.DataTableTableAdapterSchedules

<I need a way to fill the table with data from> = objAadapter.GetDataByAll(TextBoxSearch)

For Each row As System.Data.DataRow In objDataTable
    strClassName = row.ClassName
Next
```

Please help by supplying the missing coding we will need because I tried using:

```
Dim objDataTable As DataTableSchedules = objAadapter.GetDataByAll(TextBoxSearch)
```

and this error was shown:

```
Error 1 Type 'DataTableSchedules' is not defined.
```

I realize that I can set up a command object and DataReader but prefer to use objects that are already existing instead. This one has had us stuck for several days now.

Answer (score 0):

If you type DataSetSchedulesTableAdapters.DataTableTableAdapterSchedules is the data retrieving part, you will also have a class called DataSetSchedules that will have the class structure that will hold the data you retrieve and the strongly typed datatables and datarows.

```
Dim strClassName As String = ""
Dim objAadapter As New Knowledge_Academy.DataSetSchedulesTableAdapters.DataTableTableAdapterSchedules
Dim objDataTable As Knowledge_Academy.DataSetSchedules.DataSetSchedulesDataTable
Dim objDataRow As Knowledge_Academy.DataSetSchedules.DataSetSchedulesRow

objDataTable = objAadapter.GetDataByAll(TextBoxSearch)

For Each objDataRow In objDataTable.Rows
    strClassName = objDataRow.ClassName
Next
```

I am kind of guessing on some of this, but it should be very close.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I was able to use:Dim objDataTable As DataSetSchedulesTableAdapters.DataTableTableAdapterSchedules
 ok and I will update the posting for that but now I need a way to populate the object with data and put the missing coding in this line: For Each row As <> In objDataTable

Comment: Placing system.data.datarow in the For-Next worked but objDataTable displays this error because I think I'm missing a way to get the data into it: Error 3 Expression is of type 'Knowledge_Academy.DataSetSchedulesTableAdapters.DataTableTableAdapterSchedules', which is not a collection type.

Comment: I updated the coding to include system.data.datarow. Could you show a coding sample of how it should look? Thanks.

Comment: ok, do you have the option of Knowledge_Academy.DataSetSchedules.DataSetSchedulesTable or DataSetSchedulesRow.  We have used this stuff like this: Dim itemAdapterCart As New DAL.ShoppingCartTableAdapters.GetCartPackageCoursesTableAdapter
            Dim dtadc As New DAL.ShoppingCart.CartItemsRow

Comment: I think that's coming from the project name. Also that's the same name we are using for the SQL Server database. In other parts of the project we have not needed to used that as an option.

Comment: i edited my answer above, does that make any sense?  One is the retrieval, the other is the class structure for the data retrieved.  Both were created automatically and allow for strong typing like you want.  Or...maybe if you define your objDataTable as just datatable you can then just use datarow, but, you lose the strong type.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the time you are taking to help. Since this is new to me, it's confusing. Can I ask a favor? Could you send to me a small project that uses a typed DataSet / TableAdapter from the designer and code that loops through the rows for 1 of the columns? That will really help me learn how this works.

Comment: I will try to put something small together if I have the time, which I may.  Until then, just try typing Knowledge_Academy. and search through the intellisense to see if something like .DataSetSchedules exists.  Or even better, right click on Knowledge_Academy and click Go To Definition.  Search through there a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Knowledge_Academy.DataSetSchedules is there. Can you tell me how to use it to get .GetDataByAll(TextBoxSearch.Text) to get data in? Thanks.

Comment: I fixed up my answer, should be something very close to that.